# Need cookies help to save information

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view

we have multi store views site.

we provide an option to change store views through dropdown [here](http://stylebaby.com/) as below :

[image]

once we change option from dropdown, it will display selected store view.

but once we click on any other page[ menu, catalog, Product ,cms ] it will again display old store view.

but it should be in same store view until we change it manually.

Is i need  to use cookies for saving ?

**observer.php**

```
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
     public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {

      if(!empty($_GET['___from_store']))
      {
          Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($_GET['___store']);
      }
      else
      {
       $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
        $cnCode =  $geoIP->getCountry();
       // echo $cnCode;
       // echo $cnCode='IN';
            switch ($cnCode) {
                case "US": {
                      Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('india');
                      break;
                }
                case "IN": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('india');
                    break;
                }
                case "CA": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('india');
                    break;
                }
                case "UK": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('india');
                    break;
                }

                case "AU": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('india');
                    break;
                }
          }              

        }

    }
}
```

**language.phtml**

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<?php
$lis = "";
$selCurrency = $this->__('Currency');
foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang):
    if($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()){
        //This line will show SYMBOL only
        //$selCurrency = "[".Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol()."]";

        //This line will show FULLNAME
        $selCurrency = '  '.$this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName());
    }
    $lis .= '<li><a href="'.$_lang->getCurrentUrl().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()).'</a></li>';
endforeach;
?>
<div class="form-language">
    <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $selCurrency ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php echo $lis ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, looks like your **observer.php** sets the store always to "India", is that correct?

About your question, the best option is to have a separate URL for each store view, which could be a subdirectory (`example.com/store2`), subdomain (`store2.example.com`) or even a new domain (`example2.com`).

[This link](http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/subdomains-subdirectories-or-cctlds-for-global-audiences-(1).aspx) explains more about this topic.

After choosing your approach, you need to:

1. Create the Store View in Magento admin panel
2. Create the new address (subdomain, subdirectory or new domain) in you server and copy the files **index.php** and **.htaccess** to that new folder.
3. Edit the bottom of **index.php** in the line: `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` to set your RunCode (code of the store defined in Magento admin) and RunType (store or website).
4. Go to `System > Configuration > General > Web` and **make sure that you are editing the right Store View** (you can change it in the upper left corner under "Current Configuration Scope").
5. Under the tabs `Unsecure` and `Secure`, change the `Base URL` field to match your new store view URL.

After that, you need to create symlinks for the Magento files, this will allow you to keep navigating in the same store view.

Use SSH to access the root folder of your new storeview
`/home/example/example.com/html/store2/` and execute this:

```
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/includes/ includes 
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/js/ js 
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ lib 
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/media/ media 
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/skin/ skin 
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ var
```

This should solve your problem.

If you want to read more:
https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html

Comment: Thanks for nice information, but client don't want url in that way.

Comment: Oh ok...I am sorry, but I am not sure how to do that without changing URLs. I had the same problem with a client and I explained the importance of having different URLs (even as a subdirectory) as stated in [this article](http://support.mageworx.com/extensions/seo_suite_pro_and_ultimate/the_same_url_keys_for_different_websitesstore_views.html).

Comment: If I find any other helpful information I will post here. Good luck with your project and, again, if possible I would suggest talk with your client to change the approach, since is better for SEO and also user experience; although I know that sometimes is hard to change the client's mind :)

Comment: you are absolutey right regarding url structure that helps for seo & clients mind :-)