# Setting up multiple stores. Configuring one of them causes immediate redirect and can't login/view default website

Tags: multistore, store-view, base-url

I set up a website: `http://example.com`

I set up three store fronts that don't exist yet without a problem.

I created the fourth (last) store front `http://example4.com` without a problem. This domain is actually a live site that is running on my server at the moment.

Immediately after I click save on the configuration page (changing `http://example.com` to `http://example4.com` on the base+link urls (secure+unsecure) I get redirected to `example4.com` (the live site).

If I try to go to the primary website `http://example.com` I get redirected to the live `http://example4.com` as well.  This prevents me from viewing the primary site and prevents me login into to Magento at all.

If I edit the values in `core_config_data` table and clear `/var/cache/` I am able to get back to the primary site but trying to configure my 4th store immediately causes the problem again.

Any suggestions?  I need to be able to setup this last store in Magento before getting rid of the old site.

Edit : Not sure if it helps anything but changed http://example4.com to example5.com (which is a domain that is parked on top of my the same account that runs example.com).  So again I immediately get redirect to example5.com.  When I try to goto example.com/admin/ login page I get sent to the magento install/setup system on example5.com.

I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: Are you creating new websites as well or just store fronts? Because to use a different URL, you will need a new website. And then you can change the base URLs (secure and unsecure) without problems.

Comment: I have 1 website and I wanted to create 4 different store fronts.  The primary store (website) will have all products, each store front will have a slightly different design/template and a subset of the products. They should all have different domains.  So you are saying I have to create 4 different websites?  Can you explain the purpose of storefronts then? Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: I did some reading about the subject and still don't feel like I understand.  I want to clarify however that I want all customers  and orders to be under one systems and to be shared across all my stores (or whatever they are called).

Comment: Hi @hendr1x, I feel that I understand your question better now. I will answer it here.

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand: In Magento you can have multiple WebSites, Stores and/or Store Views. They are all controlled by the same admin, which means that you don't need a new database or a new Magento installation.

You manage this features in the menu `System > Manage Stores`

The basic difference between these 3 options are:

- **Store Views** are used most for language purposes (if you want to translate your store, for example)
- **Stores** are used when you need a different set of products
- **WebSites** are used when you need a different URL

[Here](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html) you can find more information about this topic.

In your case, you will need a new WebSite for each domain and each WebSite will have their own Store. With this approach you can have the different domains that you want and also different set of products in each store; but still have 1 admin panel, 1 database, etc.

I suggest you to create a new Store View then a new Store and link the Store View created with this new Store. Then, create a new WebSite and link it to the Store created.

After that, follow the steps of [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119968/need-cookies-help-to-save-information/120031#120031) to set the domain for each store.

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response.  I will try your recommended setup tonight. What I don't understand is why the have settings for domain names in the store configuration settings. If what you said is true, shouldn't they be declared on the website level?

Comment: That's a good question...I believe that you can have different URL's for stores if you use a folder, like this: `example.com/store1` and `example.com/store2` . To use a subdomain `store2.example.com` or a new domain `example2.com` I think you need a Website. But this is just my opinion, maybe someone else can explain this better :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think your solution will work for me.  It seems (based on my readings) that you can't share carts between websites. Unfortunately I don't know what to do.

Comment: That's right, you can't share carts, just the products and customers. Sorry that this does not work for you =(